# (Vue) Ant Design display client side as well as server-side validations in ant's form with v-decorator

Tags: forms, validation, vue.js, antd

I have used **Ant design**'s form component with `v-decorators` for validating forms and I want to display client side(v-decorator rule validation which I have done currently) as well as server side form data validations.

Consider this as a sample login form:

```vue
<template>
  <AForm
    :form="form"
    @submit.prevent="handleSubmit"
  >
    <FormItem>
      <AInput
        v-decorator="['email', { rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your email!' }] }]"
        placeholder="Email"
      />
    </FormItem>
    <FormItem>
      <AInput
        v-decorator="['password', { rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }] }]"
        placeholder="Password"
        type="password"
      />
    </FormItem>
    <FormItem>
      <AButton
        html-type="submit"
        class="w-full"
        :loading="loading"
      >
        Log in
      </AButton>
    </FormItem>
  </AForm>
</template>

<script>
import { Form, Input, Button } from 'ant-design-vue';
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  components: {
    AForm: Form,
    FormItem: Form.Item,
    AInput: Input,
    AButton: Button,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      form: this.$form.createForm(this),
      errors: {},
      loading: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['login']),
    handleSubmit() {
      this.errors = {};
      this.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
        if (!err) {
          this.loading = true;
          this.login(values)
            .then(() => {
              this.$router.push('/');
            })
            .catch(({ response = {}, message }) => {
              const { errors } = response.data;
              if (errors) {
                this.errors = errors; // I want to display these errors
                return;
              }
              this.$notify.error(message || 'Unable to login');
            })
            .finally(() => {
              this.loading = false;
            });
        }
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I've submitted the form data to a laravel server, and I'll eventually get some validation errors that I need to display into the ant's form. My validation error object looks like this:

```json
{
    errors: {
        email: "The email must be a valid email address.",
        password: "(some validation message here)"
    }
}
```

I don't want to loose the ant's form validation functionality and I also want to show server side validation errors along with it. Is there any way to achieve this in vue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setFields` method of form to set error state.

```
this.login(values)
.then(() => {
    this.$router.push('/');
})
.catch(({
        response = {},
        message
    }) => {
        const {
            errors
        } = response.data;
        if (errors) {
            this.form.setFields({
                'email': {
                    errors: [{
                        "message": errors.email,
                        "field": "email"
                    }]
                },
                'password': {
                    errors: [{
                        "message": errors.password,
                        "field": "password"
                    }]
                }
            });
            return;
        }
```